# Pass name to paypal in paypal checkout

Tags: javascript, paypal

I want to pass the name (and other values) to paypal to make the checkout personalized.

I've tried to code below.

```
createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '0.01'
                    }
                }],
                payer: [{
                    name: {
                        given_name: 'Alexis'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
```

I expected paypal to know the name of the payer, but it crashes instead of opening the checkout window. You can use the interactive smart button tool to test it out: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: See this link on formatting the payer name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820720/paypal-shopping-cart-custom-create-order-objects-and-user-details/55357584#55357584

Answer (score 0):

According to the API spec, the payer should be an Object, not an Array.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create